# Appropriately sized fonts on any device

Tags: css, font-size

I am currently attempting to get a website to display some plain text with appropriate font sizes on both a desktop and mobile browser. Trying to choose a font size for both results in the text being too large on desktops and too small on mobile because of the different displays.

I have attempted using a media query to change the font size based off of the screen width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  body {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

This "works", but it comes with the caveat that resizing a browser window on a desktop will result in changing the font size if the width goes to or below 900px. I never want the font size to respond dynamically to the browser size. It should always stay the same size regardless of any window resizing that occurs. I will not consider `vh` and `vw` as solutions because of this requirement.

While searching around for solutions, I came across using dpi in media queries as an alternative. Since I assume the vast majority of mobile devices have a higher dpi than most desktop monitors, that could be a good way to change the font size on mobile.

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 150dpi) {
  body {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

But what if there is a monitor that does surpass this dpi? This works for the 3 devices I am testing with, but I cannot be sure that it will work in more cases.

Overall, my aim is to get something like the setup Wikipedia has. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch The font size does not change when resizing the browser, it displays at a readable size consistently on both mobile and desktop browsers, and I assume it will work quite nicely on a high dpi monitor as well, but I have no way of testing that.

So what is the appropriate way to get the functionality I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing this question but before posting, I kept on searching for a solution and I found it. It's actually very simple, but easy to miss. I hope posting this helps others in the future. It all boils down to this line within the head of the html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

It's explained nicely here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

Average font-size for resizing screen you can get by using stylesheet calculator and properties like:

**vh** - viewport height

**vw** - viewport width.

Your font size will take same size on your view, but it can be unreadable if you don't handle small sizes layout.

For regular size: `font-size: calc(.5vh + .8vw);`

For large size: `font-size: calc(5vh + 5vw);`